# Using Backtick in Powershell: Unexpected token

Tags: powershell, backticks

In the code below, I am searching through an .ini file and trying to replace certain lines with updated configurations. I've seen it done for single lines, but I am trying to do it for multiple & different lines. When trying to use a `backtick`, I get `Unexpected token '^' in expression or statement.`.

```
$layout_choice = "TEST"
$store_pics_by_date_choice = "TEST"
$orientation_choice = "TEST"
$copy_strips_choice = $backup_path
$copy_pics_choice = "no"
$copy_gifs_choice = $backup_path
$copy_videos_choice = "no"
$viewer_monitor_choice = "TEST"

get-content $file | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "^layout =.+$", "layout = $layout_choice"` 
-replace "^store_pics_by_date =.+$", "store_pics_by_date = $store_pics_by_date_choice"
-replace "^orientation =.+$", "orientation = $orientation_choice"
-replace "^copy_strips =.+$", "copy_strips = $copy_strips_choice"
-replace "^copy_gifs =.+$", "copy_gifs = $copy_gifs_choice"
-replace "^copy_pics =.+$", "copy_pics = $copy_pics_choice"
-replace "^copy_videos =.+$", "copy_videos = $copy_videos_choice"
-replace "viewer_monitor =.+", "viewer_monitor = $viewer_monitor_choice"
-replace "viewer_monitor =.+", "viewer_monitor = $viewer_monitor_choice"} | Set-Content ($newfile)
```

Comment: Is there a space after the backtick?

Answer (score 4):

The backtick is simply [an escape character](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847755.aspx).  It works for line continuation by [escaping the carriage return](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/07/10/powershell-great-debate-backticks/).

I would recommend looking for an alternative approach:  A single line with all the code, breaking the code into multiple lines, or using another solution.

An example of an alternate solution.  Slightly more code, but less delicate than using backticks:

```
#gather up your replace pairs in an array, loop through them
$line = "abcdefg"
$replaceHash = @{
    "^store_pics_by_date =.+$" = "store_pics_by_date = blah"
    "b" = "blah"
    "c" = "cat"
}
foreach($key in $replaceHash.keys)
{
    $line = $line -replace $key, $replaceHash[$key]
}
```

Using a backtick to continue on the next line is rarely if ever the correct answer - it creates delicate code.  Even the answer from Frode F. failed, as there was a character after the first backtick.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 I agree that it's was not a good solution. It was only an attempt to fix the solution provided by OP. :) The space behind the backtick must have appeared when I copy/pasted the code.

Comment: Thanks for helping all.  I like the idea of the hash but I  ran into some issues.  Let me see what I can work out and I'll reply back if I hit another roadblock.